# convert an app to lib for others common use

Tags: ios

I hope to convert an app to lib(.a) file for other projects.
The app(lib) has self's ui, other projects use api to start the app(.a file ), the app can exit and return to the project which call it.

Is it possible?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it's possible to put **most** of an application's code into a static library archive (`.a` file), but any assets that are not compiled into the static library archive (such as nib files, plists, and images) will need to be provided as well, and will need to exist at a path that the static library can find them.